# How to add react to an existing express multipage project with ejs?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have an existing multi-page app with ejs templating, however, I would like to use React in one of the pages.

Is it possible to mix the two using webpack?

For instance, i'd like all the content on my current page to stay the same, but use React for a particular div

I am able to bundle my react files with webpack, however, not able to link it to  tag so as to make this work. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my webpack config file:

```
const path = require("path");

const outputDirectory = "dist";

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/react/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, outputDirectory),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
        loader: "url-loader?limit=100000"
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 3000
  }
};
```

I have found a way to do this by generating a production build everytime, and linking the dist bundle.js to my script file in the ejs served by express.

However, I am fairly certain that this can be done in a better fashion but unable to find a way to do it.

Comment: AFAIK this is how I've done it for a Rails app. You can also have a look at HTMLWebpackPlugin - https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can write React code simply by loading the React libraries through `<script>` tag in the `<head>` element, as long as you select the HTML element in your React code

For example if you wanted to code a like button in React, in HTML you give a unique ID:

```
<div id="like_button_container"></div>
```

Then, in JavaScript you select the element and render with React:

```
const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
ReactDOM.render(e(LikeButton), domContainer);
```

Full example can be found here by Dan Abramov: https://gist.github.com/gaearon/6668a1f6986742109c00a581ce704605

---

So in Webpack, we'll just have to find ways to add the `<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>` to the `<head>` element somehow. Depends how you've set up your `index.html`, you can either 1) add the script tag directly into `index.html` or 2) use plugins such as [html-webpack-pluign](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) to dynamically generate the `index.html`

Comment: yes I did read the script tag approach on the official documentation page,  but thats sad because i cant use jsx, and that adds a lot of biolerplate!

Comment: Secondly, I cannot use that plugin because I have an existing` index.ejs` file instead of `index.html`, so I'm not able to use html-webpack-plugin!

Comment: Try install React as `devDependencies`  in your local `node_modules`, then in any `.js` file, add `import React from "react"` to top of file and add "@babel/preset-react" loader in your webpack config for `.js` module rules. And can you add React <script> to your `index.ejs`?